# strange Hash behavior for nested assignments with defaults

Tags: ruby, hash

console output:

```
2.1.3 :011 > b = Hash.new( Hash.new([]) )
 => {}
2.1.3 :012 > b[:a][:b] << 'hello'
 => ["hello"]
2.1.3 :013 > b
 => {}
2.1.3 :014 > b.size
 => 0
2.1.3 :015 > b.keys
 => []
2.1.3 :016 > b[:a][:b]
 => ["hello"]
```

Why is that I can access the value stored at `b[:a][:b]` yet `b` has a size of 0 and no keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`new(obj) → new_hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new)

> If `obj` is specified, this single object will be used for all default values.

Now `Hash.new([])` is holding the *default `Array`* object. Now `b[:a][:b] << 'hello'` you are entering, the `"hello"` to the default `Array`.The *default* value is being returned, when the *key* doesn't exist in the `Hash`.

Don't think you are adding keys to the Hash objects, with this `b[:a][:b] << 'hello' line.`

`b[:a]` is giving the *default `Hash`* object, which is `Hash.new([])`. Now on this `Hash` object you are calling `Hash#[]` using the key `:b`, but as `:b` is the non existent key, it is giving the *default `Array`* object.

That's why `b`, `b.size` and `b.keys` all are proving that `Hash` is empty.

Finally.

> Why is that I can access the value stored at b[:a][:b] yet b has a size of 0 and no keys?

Because, you added the value `"Hello"` to the default `Array`, as I mentioned above. That value is coming when you are using the line `b[:a][:b]`.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean, I created a single object the first time, which is being returned as the default always. Checked this with `b[:a][:c]` which also returned `["hello"]`. So, how do I accomplish the goal, which is to have a Hash of Hashes, where I can succinctly create two levels of keys and have a default array value at the same time?

Comment: @JoshDiehl Try this `new {|hash, key| block }` from the same link..Read documentation example.

Comment: That syntax does work, this is what I'll use: `b = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] =  Hash.new {|h2, k2| h2[k2] = []}}`.  Sure enough as you said it is right in the documentation, I just didn't think to look because it seems so counter-intuitive.  I wonder if the case for wanting to use some single object as a default is more common than wanting to execute a new block.

Comment: @JoshDiehl That's why it is present there.. :-D

Comment: @JoshDiehl The "default default" is `nil`, a single object. An often  (most?) used "non-default default" is 0 (for counting things with `+= 1`), also a single object.